# MoleculerJs with Jaeger tracing: how to trace follow up action calls (new spans) in one trace

Tags: javascript, jaeger, moleculer, moleculer-web

I would like to display all my traces like in the examples from the [moleculer-jaeger package](https://github.com/moleculerjs/moleculer-metrics/tree/master/packages/moleculer-jaeger#readme):
[image: What i would like to have]

But what i get is something like this:
[image: What i get with my current config]
All spans you can see in this picture should be within the main trace (gateway).

Here is my moleculer.config:

```json
tracing: {
        enabled   : true,
        stackTrace: true,
        actions   : true,
        exporter  : {
            type   : 'Jaeger',
            options: {
                // HTTP Reporter endpoint. If set, HTTP Reporter will be used.
                endpoint: 'http://jaeger:14268/api/traces',
                // UDP Sender host option.
                host    : 'api.dev.host.com',
                // UDP Sender port option.
                port    : 6832,
                // Jaeger Sampler configuration.
                sampler : {
                    // Sampler type. More info: https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.14/sampling/#client-sampling-configuration
                    type   : 'Const',
                    // Sampler specific options.
                    options: {
                    }
                },
                // Additional options for `Jaeger.Tracer`
                tracerOptions: {},
                // Default tags. They will be added into all span tags.
                defaultTags  : {
                    appName: 'core',
                }
            }
        },
        tags: {
            action: {
                // Always add the response
                response: true,
            }, 
        },
},
```

My jaeger-service is just one of the examples:

```js
const JaegerService = require('moleculer-jaeger')

module.exports = {
    mixins  : [ JaegerService ],
    settings: {
        host   : 'jaeger-server',
        port   : 6832,
        sampler: {
            type   : 'Const',
            options: {
                decision: 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried several different configurations for sampling but nothing worked the way i would like it to have.

Here is some code where you can see the action calls i do:

```js
// serviceX endpoint:
resolveByName: {
    rest  : 'GET resolve/name/:name',
    params: {
        name: { type: 'string' }
    },
    handler(ctx) {
        return resolveByNameHandler(this.broker, ctx.params, 'serviceY')
    }
},


// handler code
// please do not focus on the code itself. What i wanted to show is how i call the other
// services. 
const { NotFoundError } = require(`${process.env.INIT_CWD}/util/error`)

module.exports = (broker, params, dataSource) =>  {
    const { name } = params
    const query = { name: name }
    
    const rejectRequest = (name, data) => Promise.reject(new NotFoundError(name, data))

    const getSourceData = result => broker.call(`${dataSource}.find`, { query: { id: result[0].ownerId } })
        .then(sourceData => sourceData.length === 0
            ? rejectRequest(dataSource, sourceData)
            : mergeResult(sourceData, result))

    const mergeResult = (sourceData, result) => ({ ...sourceData[0], origin: { ...result[0], source: 'serviceX' } })

    return broker.call('serviceX.find', { query: query })
        .then(result => result.length === 0 ? rejectRequest('serviceX', query): result)
        .then(result => result[0].ownerId ? getSourceData(result) : rejectRequest('noOwnerId', query))
}
```

What i also tried is to not use the moleculer-jaeger package but to use the jaeger all-in-one docker image. Same results though...

```yaml
# from the docker-compose.yml
  jaeger-server:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
    ports:
      - 5775:5775/udp
      - 6831:6831/udp
      - 6832:6832/udp
      - 5778:5778
      - 16686:16686
      - 14268:14268
      - 9411:9411
    networks:
      - internal
```

What i do not want to do is to set the spans manually in every service. I have tried it already but it did not work at all, so if this would be the only solution i would be very happy to see an example.

Thanks in advance!

*edit:
The Versions i use:

```json
{
    "jaeger-client": "^3.18.1",
    "moleculer": "^0.14.13",
    "moleculer-db": "^0.8.12",
    "moleculer-db-adapter-mongoose": "^0.8.9",
    "moleculer-jaeger": "^0.2.3",
    "moleculer-web": "^0.9.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.5",
}
```

Comment: which version of the moleculer?

Comment: @IvanZhuravlev added the versions for moleculer and jaeger-client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This version already has a built-in jager tracer, see the [documentation](https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/tracing.html#Jaeger).
2. In order for the events to be nested, it is necessary to transfer the context inside the actions, use `ctx.call` calls instead of `broker.call`, so they will be nested.
3. To quickly receive support for the moleculer, join us in [discord](https://discord.gg/XHQtdD5r)!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have  a follow up question but i will go to the discord channel and ask it there!